# image is stretched in carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a carousel with images. But the images are stretched. Can anyone help me that the images aren't stretched?

[image: stretched]

here is my code:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <img src="/images/winkelstufe.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h1>lorem</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore, quis!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

my css:

```
.carousel-item {
  height: 32rem;
}

.carousel-item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 32rem; 
  display: block;
}
.carousel {
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
  position: relative;
}
.carousel-caption {
  bottom: 3rem;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Can someone help me what to do that the images isn't shown as stretched?

Comment: sidenote `col-xs-12` is just `col-12` in bs4

Comment: but now it took the whole screen and it got a white bar around the carousel. I want the height to be ```32rem``` but the img not stretched.

Answer (score 0):

you have a `w-100` class on the image, which sets the `width: 100%` - remove this class.

You also have a `d-block` class on the image which sets `display:block` but you've also set the same rule in your CSS.  You can also remove this class since it's not doing anything for you.

Also, remove the `col-xs-12 col-sm-12` classes from the `carousel-item`. Those `col-*` classes are only supposed to be applied to columns that are direct children of a `<div class="row">` and this is not.

Comment: Now the image is much smaller. Please see my answer

Comment: I see your new answer, and yes the image is now smaller because it's no longer stretched.  You were asking why the image was stretched and how to not do that... did this not answer your question?